# How the VC++ 2005/2008 Debugger visualizers would stop working?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I suddenly found that Debugger visualizers do not work for STL containers such as vector, set. Nothing went corrupt except that the watch windows showed things as if the visualiser were not there. But they are there, autoexp.dat sits right C:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger. And They used to work, I did not know when it stopped.

I have  VC++ 2005 and 2008 installed side by side. Both worked before, but neither now.

Does any one have any clue?
(for those who do not know what are the visualizers, please see [this link](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/kate/article.php/c15291__1/) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself, just open the visual studio command prompt and run this command:

---

c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>devenv /ResetSettings

---

which virtually reset the IDE to the stage it was freshly installed.

Everything seems OK now.